# Symfony unit testing with loginUser(), login not working (returning 302 to login page)

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, symfony5

I'm building a test for a Symfony 5.4 application.

I have created a test like this:

```
public function testCreateProduct() {
    $client = static::createClient();
    /** @var User $mainAdmin */
    $mainAdmin = static::getContainer()->get(UserRepository::class)->find(1);

    //$client->catchExceptions(false);
    $client->loginUser($mainAdmin);

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/en/product/new');

    $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
    $this->assertSelectorTextContains('span.username', $mainAdmin->getUsername());

}
```

But the login is not working, I get a 302 redirect to the login page, and if I set `catchExceptions(false)` I get an `AccessDeniedException`.

How can I debug this?

---

Edit:
I tried to change the patch to a public route, then I did a `dd($this->getUser(), $request)`

`getUser()` is null, but the request session contains the user:

```
#session: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session {#16616
#storage: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\MockFileSessionStorage {#16631
  -savePath: "C:\www\project\var\cache\test/sessions"
  #id: "a9d00704e1a0211d06ebddadfaabbf0188e9d65d94faac05afbdc63bb9fb7caa"
  #name: "MOCKSESSID"
  #started: true
  #closed: false
  #data: array:3 [
    "_sf2_attributes" => &1 array:1 [
      "_security_main" => "O:52:"Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\TestBrowserToken":2:{i:0;s:4:"main";i:1;a:5:{i:0;C:15:"App\Entity\User":118:{a:5:{i:0;i:2;i:1;s:5:"admin";i:2;s:60:"$2y$13$abcdefghi......";i:3;i:1;i:4;b:0;}}i:1;b:1;i:2;N;i:3;a:0:{}i:4;a:9:{i:0;s:9:"ROLE_USER";i:1;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";i:2;[...]}}}"
    ]
    "_sf2_meta" => &2 array:3 [
      "u" => 1645718565
      "c" => 1645718565
      "l" => 0
    ]
    "_symfony_flashes" => &3 []
  ]
```

---

I see a difference between
`$request->getSession()->getBag('attributes')`
done in dev (working) vs in test: in dev I have `_security_secured_area`, while in test I have `_security_main`. May this be the reason?

Answer (score 4):

Solved.

Since I was using a custom firewall name in `security.yaml`, in my case `secured_area`, I had to pass that as the second parameter of `loginUser()`:

```
$client->loginUser($mainAdmin, 'secured_area');
```

Comment: Thanks; this saved me some time! The documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/6.0/testing.html#logging-in-users-authentication) doesn't mention this. Still, I feel stupid that I didn't notice this myself by simply checking the methods parameters.